# Изменить значения в БД без грида и DataSet

Tags: c#, ado.net

Работаю в WinForms. У меня есть метод который возвращает DataTable (таблица из 2х столбиков : цена, название). Затем Столбики DataTable заполняют массивы List<>. DataSet не использую. Вопрос как мне изменить в БД только одно значение цены если известно значение названия? Пытаюсь вызвать Adapter.Update(); Но метод требует DataSet в качестве параметра. Можно ли без него обойтись ?

```
     public void saveNewMaterialNamePrise(int newPrise, string name)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(@"update Materials SET Prise=@priseNew where (Name=@selectedName)", conn);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"priseNew", newPrise);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"selectedName", name);
                adapter.UpdateCommand = update;
                adapter.Update();  //Требует DataSet которого нет
                conn.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь вам не надо исползовать `SqlDataAdapter` и `UpdateCommand`.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(@"update Materials SET Prise=@priseNew where (Name=@selectedName)", conn);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"priseNew", newPrise);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"selectedName", name);
    conn.Open();
    update.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: вот блин. 2 дня думал  а решение было таким простым. Спасибо!